# Can django_admin_log be monitored through Django's admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

The table `django_admin_log` is useful to monitor the actions of users in the admin.  Right now, I can achieve that by querying the database directly.  Is there a built-in functionality where I can view the table `django_admin_log` through Django's admin for all users?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can't you just:

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
admin.site.register(LogEntry)
```

In one of your admin.py files? I just tested it and it is barebones but it works.

You might want to be more specific and create a `ModelAdmin` class for LogEntry to provide for a better list view and maybe some filtering abilities. But that should work.

Comment: hi, I did the same but I'd get `KeyError at /admin/   Log entries`, and I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 8):

Here's my version.  [Reference for fields available.](http://djangoapi.quamquam.org/trunk/django.contrib.admin.models.LogEntry-class.html)

```
class LogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Create an admin view of the history/log table"""
    list_display = ('action_time','user','content_type','change_message','is_addition','is_change','is_deletion')
    list_filter = ['action_time','user','content_type']
    ordering = ('-action_time',)
    #We don't want people changing this historical record:
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        #returning false causes table to not show up in admin page :-(
        #I guess we have to allow changing for now
        return True
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

Comment: You can make the fields read only: `readonly_fields = [ 'user','content_type','object_id','object_repr','action_flag','change_message']` - you'll still be able to click on save, but not make any changes.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a more extensive admin configuration for viewing all log entries that relies on Django 2.1 view-only permissions:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry, DELETION
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.urls import reverse

@admin.register(LogEntry)
class LogEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    date_hierarchy = 'action_time'
    readonly_fields = ('action_time',)
    list_filter = ['user', 'content_type']
    search_fields = ['object_repr', 'change_message']
    list_display = ['__str__', 'content_type', 'action_time', 'user', 'object_link']

    # keep only view permission
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def object_link(self, obj):
        if obj.action_flag == DELETION:
            link = obj.object_repr
        else:
            ct = obj.content_type
            try:
                link = mark_safe('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (
                                 reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (ct.app_label, ct.model),
                                         args=[obj.object_id]),
                                 escape(obj.object_repr),
                ))
            except NoReverseMatch:
                link = obj.object_repr
        return link
    object_link.admin_order_field = 'object_repr'
    object_link.short_description = 'object'

    def queryset(self, request):
        return super(LogEntryAdmin, self).queryset(request) \
            .prefetch_related('content_type')
```

It is based on [this Django snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2484/) and the result looks like this:

[image: screenshot of log entries]

If you want to use it with earlier Django versions, see [this earlier revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50308400/7) of this answer.

Comment: Great to have the custom list view :)

Answer (score 1):

Few points from my experience:

- It's good to make all fields read only.
  One reason is obviously because those are logs and should not be mutable, but another is performance. If you allow changing users for example, loading of change page on it's own can be issue if you have hundreds of thousands of users as in my case. Otherwise you can use `raw_id_fields`.
- Content type filter values are unsorted by model so it's unfriendly, but don't have nice generic solution to share.
- I also created filter for action as orignal model does not have `CHOICES` field and using just `action_flag` as filter will show 1,2,3 as choices, which isn't very user friendly:

  ```
  class ActionFlagFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
      title = 'Action flag filter'

      parameter_name = 'action_flag'

      def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
          return (
              (ADDITION, "Add"),
              (CHANGE, "Change"),
              (DELETION, "Delete"),
          )

      def queryset(self, request, queryset):
          if self.value():
              return queryset.filter(action_flag=self.value())
          return queryset
  ```